# Akka version collision between Flink and Play 2.5

Tags: playframework, akka, apache-flink, playframework-2.5, flink-streaming

In our project we have a Flink (1.1.3) streaming job that reads from one kafka queue, performs a map function transformation and writes to another queue.

This was working well until we introduced an outgoing REST request as part of the flow.
To do this we used the PlayFramework WSClient (as it is used in other places of our stack), and created it in the code in this way:

```
  val config = new AhcWSClientConfig(wsClientConfig = WSClientConfig())
  val builder = new AhcConfigBuilder(config)
  val ahcConfig = builder.configure().build()
  new AhcWSClient(ahcConfig)(ActorMaterializer()(ActorSystem()))
```

This worked well locally, but when deploying it and running on a cluster, I got this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.util.Helpers$.toRootLowerCase(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at akka.stream.StreamSubscriptionTimeoutSettings$.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:491)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializerSettings$.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:243)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializerSettings$.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:232)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializer$$anonfun$1.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:41)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializer$$anonfun$1.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:41)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializer$.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:41)
    at com.ourstuff.etl.core.utils.web.GlobalWSClient$.generateClient(WSClientFactory.scala:32)
```

Investigating into it, I assumed this is a collision between Akka 2.3.x (brought by Flink 1.1.X) and Akka 2.4.x (brought by PlayFramework).

We upgraded the Flink cluster to 1.3.1 (as well as our code's dependency on Flink), assuming this will solve the issue. But the same issue seems to persist.

Any idea on what might still be causing this?

Comment: Flink 1.3.1 still uses Akka 2.3 (well technically a custom 2.3 build called flakka).

Comment: @ChesnaySchepler considering Flink 1.3.1 uses it's own custom version of akka (flaka) why would there be a collision with Play that looks for akka in the clathpath?

Comment: Just to update on top of that.
I've ran on sbt
`whatDependsOn "com.typesafe.akka" "akka-actor_2.11" "2.3.7"`

and it didn't yield any results.

Comment: The collision still occurs because flakka is just a repackaging of akka with some backported patches. Specifically, the packages for all classes are identical, which is the only thing the classloader cares about.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to resolve this dependency conflict is by [relocating the conflicting classes into a different namespace](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html#resolving-dependency-conflicts-with-flink-using-the-maven-shade-plugin).

Comment: Considering the conflicting classes are within akka-actor, which is a dependency of Play, I will need to shadow the play framework as well, and all of our "common" libraries that depend on it.   
That will have a very serious cascading effect. Is this the only option?

Comment: Also as I have mentioned in a comment on my original question, Flink 1.3.1 technically shadows akka (by using "flakka" instead), so that in itself should solve the issue, though it doesn't.